# Bootstrap 3 sticky footer at the bottom and 100% height container with content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my css rules:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
}
```

Using this example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

I can make sticky footer without any issues, however there's one problem. How can i make content container to be full height 100%?

[image]

I want to fill this gray background color to the footer. How is that possible? I spent 8 hours already to figure out that. Please, help.

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/3wh7d612/1/
Pay attention to div with class `container2` i want to make it full height till the footer.

Comment: Read carefuly the comments on the CSS ... http://www.bootply.com/1j3XQATeU3 ... and check your html structure

Comment: Thanks, it makes `#wrap` full height, but what if i have 2 containers inside that `#wrap`? like that:

`<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container1"></div>
    <div class="container2"></div>
</div>`

and i want to make `.container2` to fit window height?

Please, take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/3wh7d612/ class "container2" with white background not 100% height

Comment: It would seem you are going about solving the problem incorrectly as there is no reason for a footer if you want HTML content at 100% height

Answer (score 0):

Amongst the newer responsive CSS selectors, my favorites are definitely vw (Viewport Width) and vh (Viewport Height). A lot of web designs that have come my way call for full page layouts with no containing max-width and no overflow of content that requires scrolling to view. These designs also feature vertical boxes that should collectively be visible within the viewport at the same time regardless of the browser’s height when scaled responsively. When researching to find a CSS solution to this, I stumbled upon the vh/vw units.

Maybe you can use it like this

```
.content {         
min-height: 80vh;  // Define based on your needs
}
```